# Grab value of excerpt_length

Tags: posts, excerpt

I know how to "set" the excerpt length for posts, but if I need to actually grab this integer value for something else, do you have any idea how I can grab/echo out just the value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could store the length like this.

```
function store_excerpt_length($length) {
    update_option( 'excerpt_length', $length );
    return $length;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'store_excerpt_length', 1000 );
```

Then use the following code to get the length.

```
echo get_option( 'excerpt_length' );
```

Comment: Nice thinking, that's probably about the only way to do it. I would just add to give your filter an arbitrarily high priority (ie `add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'store_excerpt_length', 1000 );` to make sure it checks after any other filters have operated.

Comment: You have a point there @goldeapples. Will update my answer with the priority.

Comment: Meh - isn't actually echoing anything out. I do have a function that is setting the excerpt: `function of_excerpt_length($length) {
 return 40;
}` but I wouldn't think that would actually be effecting that. Thanks!

Comment: You sure? Its working fine on my end. Where have you placed the code and what priority have you assigned to your filter?

Comment: The function that you are calling can also be modified in the following manner `of_excerpt_length($length) { $length = 40; update_option( 'excerpt_length', $length );
 return $length; }`